# VBA Copy Paste string search

Tags: vba, excel

I can’t seem to figure out how to write a vba code that search’s through cells C10:G10 to find a match that equals cell A10, once found, copies range A14:A18 to the matched cell but below e.g F14:F18 (See Image)

Macro below

```
'Copy
Range("A14:A18").Select
Selection.Copy
'Paste
Range("F14:F18").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste!
```

[image: Attached image click here]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
With Sheets("SheetName") ' Change to your actual sheet name
    Dim r As Range: Set r = .Range("C10:G10").Find(.Range("A10").Value2, , , xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Offset(4, 0).Resize(5).Value2 = .Range("A14:A18").Value2
End With
```

Range Object have [`Find Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195730(v=office.11).aspx) to help you find values within your range.
The Range object that matches your search criteria is then returned.
To get your values to the correct location, simply use `Offset and Resize Method`.

**Edit1:** To answer OP's comment

To find formulas in Ranges, you need to set `LookIn` argument to `xlFormulas`.

```
Set r = .Range("C10:G10").Find(What:=.Range("A10").Formula, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

Above code find Ranges with exactly the same formula as Cell A10.

Comment: L42 - How do i get this to work if the find and search values are formulas? ..I've tried changing the .Value2 but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim RangeToSearch As Range
Dim ValueToSearch
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Set RangeToSearch = ActiveSheet.Range("C10:G10")
Set RangeToCopy = ActiveSheet.Range("A14:A18")

ValueToSearch = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, "A").Value
For Each cell In RangeToSearch
    If cell.Value = ValueToSearch Then
        RangeToCopy.Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(14, cell.Column), _
            ActiveSheet.Cells(18, cell.Column)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: avoid usage of the `select` method, this is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

another additional variants

1.Using  `For each` loop

```
Sub test()
Dim Cl As Range, x&

For Each Cl In [C10:G10]
    If Cl.Value = [A10].Value Then
        x = Cl.Column: Exit For
    End If
Next Cl

If x = 0 Then
    MsgBox "'" & [A10].Value & "' has not been found in range 'C10:G10'!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Range(Cells(14, x), Cells(18, x)).Value = [A14:A18].Value

End Sub
```

2.Using `Find` method (already posted by L42, but a bit different)

```
Sub test2()
Dim Cl As Range, x&

On Error Resume Next

x = [C10:G10].Find([A10].Value2, , , xlWhole).Column

If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox "'" & [A10].Value2 & "' has not been found in range 'C10:G10'!"
    Exit Sub
End If

[A14:A18].Copy Range(Cells(14, x), Cells(18, x))

End Sub
```

3.Using `WorksheetFunction.Match`

```
Sub test2()
Dim Cl As Range, x&

On Error Resume Next

x = WorksheetFunction.Match([A10], [C10:G10], 0) + 2

If Err.Number > 0 Then
    MsgBox "'" & [A10].Value2 & "' has not been found in range 'C10:G10'!"
    Exit Sub
End If

[A14:A18].Copy Range(Cells(14, x), Cells(18, x))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
    Sub DoIt()
    Dim rng As Range, f As Range
    Dim Fr As Range, Crng As Range

    Set Fr = Range("A10")
    Set Crng = Range("A14:A18")
    Set rng = Range("C10:G19")
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=Fr, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then
        Crng.Copy Cells(14, f.Column)
    Else: MsgBox "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```