# VBA Copy Paste formula search

Tags: vba, excel

Code below taken from a previous question asked

My Question - How do i get this to work if the find and search values are formulas? ..I've tried changing the .Value2 but doesn't seem to work.

[VBA Copy Paste string search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085470/vba-copy-paste-string-search)

```
With Sheets("SheetName") ' Change to your actual sheet name
Dim r As Range: Set r = .Range("C10:G10").Find(.Range("A10").Value2, , , xlWhole)
If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Offset(4, 0).Resize(5).Value2 = .Range("A14:A18").Value2
```

End With

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the results of formulas, you need to specify `xlValues` for the LookIn parameter.  When it's blank it defaults to `xlFormulas`. For example, to find any formula that results in "Bar" (i.e. `=CONCATENATE("B","a","r")`) on Sheet "foo", you would do this:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Foo")
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = .UsedRange.Find("Bar", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print r.Address
    End If
End With
```

If you want to find a sheet that contains the actual formula you can either leave out the LookIn parameter entirely or explicitly specify it:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Foo")
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = .UsedRange.Find("=CONCATENATE(""B"",""a"",""r"")", , _
                            xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print r.Address
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Your code worked wonderfully. I've changed the code to copy forumlas, 
works find expect that i get a run time error of '424' - Object required. I'm I missing something? Many thanks

Comment: With Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your actual sheet name Dim r As       Range: Set r = .Range("C10:G10").Find(.Range("A10").Value2, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then r.Offset(4, 0).Resize(5).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormulas) = .Range("A14:A18").Copy
End With

Comment: @Elixir - You can't set `.Paste = .Copy`.  Copy moves to the clipboard, paste moves from it. Put `.Range("A14:A18").Copy` on one line, followed by `r.Offset(4, 0).Resize(5).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormulas)`